# How to make Rails 3 JSON parse doubly quoted strings and single number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

## Background

On the [json.org](http://www.json.org/) website, a string is defined as `"char+"` where `char+` is one or more `char`. A `char` is any unicode character except `"` or `\`. A subset of control characters are allowed, just escape them:

`"foo"` `"2"` `"\\"`

In Javascript, if you want to parse a string, it needs to be enclosed:

`"\"foo\""` or `'"foo"'`, but not `"'foo'"`

In Rails 3, the [JSON gem](http://flori.github.io/json/) that runs C or pure Ruby code is default.

---

As per the accepted answer, the gem parses JSON documents rather than elements. A document is either a collection in the form of key, value (object/hash) or values (array).

## The problem

### Strings

Let's say we want to parse the string `foo`, We would need to enclose it as `"\"foo\""` or `'"foo"'`

```
JSON.parse("\"foo\"")
JSON.parse('"foo"')
```

yield

```
JSON::ParserError unexpected token at '"foo"'
```

meaning it can't parse `"foo"`

### Numbers

The same goes for numbers: `'3'` or `"3"` will yield `Needs at least two octets`. 
Larger numbers ( an octet is a byte, so two utf8 characters are two bytes ): `'42'` or `"42"` simply yield the same `JSON::ParserError unexpected token at '42'`

## The workaround

The gem correctly parses these things if they are in an array: `'["foo"]'` or `'[3]'`

```
jsonstring = '"foo"'
JSON.parse( "[#{jsonstring}]" )[0]
```

yields

```
"foo"
```

This is ridiculous. Am I not understanding something correctly? Or is this gem bugged?

Comment: This is just weird / inconsistent with `to_json` method: `"foo".to_json => "\"foo\""`, but `JSON.parse("foo".to_json) => JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '"foo"'` (using gem json-1.8.0)

Comment: @MichalKováč :  `irb(main):008:0> JSON.parse("[#{"foo".to_json}]")  
=> ["foo"]`
A bit confusing but `to_json` method ensures that the data is correctly escaped so that it can be inserted into a JSON object, the method doesn't create a JSON object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[json.org](http://www.json.org) states:

**JSON is built on two structures:**

- A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
- An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

Since `"foo"` is neither of the above you are getting the error message. To further concrete it have a look at [Ruby JSON Parser](http://flori.github.io/json/doc/index.html), the documenation states:

> To create a valid JSON document you have to make sure, that the output is embedded in either a JSON array [] or a JSON object {}. The easiest way to do this, is by putting your values in a Ruby Array or Hash instance.

Hence what you are mentioning as "workaround" is actually the correct way to parse a string using the JSON parser.

**Additional Info:**

Parsing `"\"foo\""` on [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) and [json.parser.online.fr](http://json.parser.online.fr/) raises an error, 
parsing `["foo"]` passes the validation test on both the sites.

Comment: The same is for numbers and etc.

Comment: I figured JSON.parse parses JSON elements rather than documents.